# Apk doesn't work after changing compileSdkVersion to android-P

Tags: android

It's really strange, I created a new empty project and then I changed in file settings compileSdkVersion from 27.1 Oreo to android-P, then I refactored app to AndroidX and it's working fine if I run it on emulator or via adb connect with my device. But when I try to build apk and install it on my phone here's problem appear - 'App not installed'. But before I changed compileSdkVersion apk installs fine.

Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="ru.scapegoats.myapplicationmmmm">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".main"
            android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        </application>

</manifest>
```

Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 'android-P'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ru.scapegoats.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jre7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0-alpha3'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0-alpha3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0-alpha3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0-alpha3'
}
```

Comment: clean project and build apk

Comment: which OS version are you trying to install the APK?

Comment: 4.4.2 kitkat more then minsdk

Comment: clean doesn't help

Comment: maybe it fault of AS 3.2 preview?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot install app with `compileSdkVersion 'android-P'` preview version on older OS.

Since beta release for Android P is out, change `compileSdkVersion` to 28:

`compileSdkVersion 28`

**Note:** Ensure you have internet connection so that proper SDK updates can be downloaded.

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm really obliged.

Comment: @Andrew no problem. Enjoy coding :-)